# Python: Find a CSV file on any computer/operating system

Tags: python, pandas, csv, operating-system, platform

my name is Taliesin. I am working on a school project for which I have to perform multiple data analysis. First of all, I need a code that searches the entire computer for my file, by name. At the moment I have a code, which I borrowed from another thread on Stack overflow, but I need it to also work on different operating systems, like mac. Also with the code that I use right now, I don't know how to convert the outcome, into something that I can open with `pd.read_csv()`.

This is my code so far:

```
def find_file(root_folder, rex):
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(root_folder):
        for f in files:
            result = rex.search(f)
            if result:
                print(os.path.join(root, f))
                break # if you want to find only one

def find_file_in_all_drives(file_name):
    #create a regular expression for the file
    rex = re.compile(file_name)
    for drive in win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings().split('\000')[:-1]:
        find_file( drive, rex )


find_file_in_all_drives( "AB_NYC_2019.csv" )

df_location = find_file_in_all_drives( "AB_NYC_2019.csv" )
df = pd.read_csv(r'"{}"'.format(df_location))
```

So to summarize my questions:

1: How do I change my code so that it works on any platform?

2: How can I use the path that comes out of the code, read it as a `csv` using pandas?

I am entirely new to python. I learned the basics through Datacamp for my study.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: don't add `" "` to filename - `pd.read_csv(df_location)`

Comment: linux/mac doesn't have drives but it mounts every device as folder - so you need only `find_file("/", "AB_NYC_2019.csv")`

Comment: Now when I use pd.read_csv(df_location), i get an error. When i use print(df_location) it returns "None". Somehow the variable does not contain the path which I retrieved with the function. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: you didn't use `return location`  in `find_file_in_all_drives`. And you didn't use `return result` in `find_file` - so they automatically use `return None`. BTW: `print()` doesn't return value to other function - it only display it on screen (sometimes we say  "print returns value" but it returns only on screen)

Comment: I added both now, although I get the error that location is undefined! Sorry my Python knowledge is very basic unfortunately!

Comment: I created a new thread to get the last pieces of code right. My issue is finally resolved. Thanks all!

Link to thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58368061/python-how-do-i-assign-the-result-of-my-function-to-a-variable-that-i-can-read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mac is a Linux-based OS. So, for Mac and Linux, you can use the '**find**' utility from the terminal itself.

To search a specific directory (e.g. /home/project/csv) -

```
find /home/project/csv | grep "AB_NYC_2019.csv"
```

To search the entire filesystem -

```
find / | grep "AB_NYC_2019.csv"
```

---

However, if you still want it as part of your python program, you can run

```
import subprocess

paths = [line.decode("utf-8") for line in subprocess.check_output("find /home/project/csv | grep 'AB_NYC_2019.csv'", shell=True)]
```

This will find all such files in the search directory, and return a list of their paths.

---

To determine on which system your python program is running,

```
import platform
platform.system() 
#Darwin  - for Mac OS
#Linux   - for Linux
#Windows - for Windows
```

You can set an if-condition on the value of platform.system() and run either find function accordingly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank alot for the quick respons! I am going to puzzle with it and let you know how it went!!