# Python: How do I assign the result of my function to a variable that i can read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, function, csv

The code that I have determines which Operating System is being used. Then it has to search the entire system for my csv file. When it's found I need to be able to read in the csv file (so that its not just inside the function, but useable throughout my code).

So far I am able to locate my file, but I am having trouble to assign the filepath to a variable, so that I can read in that variabel with `pd.read_csv()`

the code that I have is at follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import re
import win32api

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13067686/search-files-in-all-drives-using-python
def find_file(root_folder, rex):
        for root,dirs,files in os.walk(root_folder):
            for f in files:
                result = rex.search(f)
                if result:
                    print(os.path.join(root, f))
                    return result
                    break # if you want to find only one

def find_file_in_all_drives(file_name):
        #create a regular expression for the file
        rex = re.compile(file_name)
        for drive in win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings().split('\000')[:-1]:
           find_file( drive, rex )
        return 

#file_name = "AB_NYC_2019.csv"
#find_file_in_all_drives(file_name)

df_location = find_file_in_all_drives( "AB_NYC_2019.csv" )
df = pd.read_csv(df_location)
```

I think that something is not right with the `return`.

Thank you for your time.

Right now it returns "None"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't returned anything from anywhere.

I'm considering your code to be working and I've placed the necessary `return` calls but haven't tested it:

```
def find_file(root_folder, rex):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_folder):
        for f in files:
            result = rex.search(f)
            if result:
                file_path = os.path.join(root, f)
                return file_path

def find_file_in_all_drives(file_name):
    matching_files = list()
    # create a regular expression for the file
    rex = re.compile(file_name)
    for drive in win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings().split('\000')[:-1]:
        file_path = find_file(drive, rex)
        if file_path:
            matching_files.append(file_path)
    return matching_files

df_location = find_file_in_all_drives("AB_NYC_2019.csv")
first_file_df = pd.read_csv(df_location[0])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am entirely new to Python and composed this code based on many other threads. This however is the missing key for it to work as I need it to work! I wish I could up vote your solution, but unfortunately my account is not allowed to do that yet. I am very thankful tho!!!

Comment: @TaliesinRSalomonson please select the tick on the answer